# Permissions, don't even know how to resolve without reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, users

Alright so what I've done, I installed Ubuntu, moved some files while in windows, this caused ubuntu to stop working. I reinstalled it the other day and now that I've set it all up how I wanted it I've found that the permissions are on another account which doesn't exist? Not sure if this makes sense but when I bring up system monitor or terminal the account name isn't the one I'm logged into, and there is no way to log into the other account

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work. Just giving the answer out of intuition.

- Try creating a new account with the same name as the Other Account (Old One).
- Then use chown with root permissions to change the ownership to your new account.